# c#/.NET: How do I execute a list of synchronous calls in parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Case:

I am coding against a legacy API, for which I have a client library (.NET dll's). I need to contact the API a bunch of times, say 3, but the API is very slow and non-asynchronous, so I would like to send the 3 requests in parallel and continue execution on my thread, when all 3 requests have returned.

Having done this earlier with asynchronous stuff, I would do something like this:

```cs
var tasks = someObjects.Select(o => _apiClient.DoSomeAsynchronousStuff(o));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var executedTask in tasks) {
    var result = executedTask.Result;
}
```

But now I need to do it with non-async stuff.

I have tried:

```cs
var tasks = someObjects.Select(o => new Task<TResult>(() => _apiClient.DoSomeSlowThreadBlockingStuff(o)));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    var result = task.Result;
}
```

I have also tried using WhenAll as in first example. In all cases, when debugging, it "stops" or doesn't return to main thread or something, after I hit the Task.WaitAll line.

What to do?

Comment: Use `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Use `Task.Run` to wrap synchronous code in a task, but if the API has support for asynchronous programming in some places but not all, you might end up calling into code that isn't safe to run in parallel.

Comment: @FCin or `Parallel.Invoke`; but ultimately, the real question here is : does the legacy API support concurrency? and if it does: will it actually help the performance (it isn't guaranteed)?

Comment: does `DoSomeAsynchronousStuff` actually return a `Task<T>`? is it actually async in the `async` sense?

Comment: `new Task<TResult>(` doesn't  *start* a task. It creates a cold task which frankly, you don't need. Use `Task.Run` instead and then `var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The first was an example. This API I'm trying to hit, has no async stuff whatsoever. @Marc I have no idea, unfortunately, and think the task of breaking up the "black box" would be very time-consuming, for me at least. As for you last question, yes, `DoSomeAsynchronousStuff` would be true async, but that's unfortunately only wishful thinking in this case :)

Comment: Thanks, guys. Using Task.Run instead of new'ing up a Task was the fix to my mistake. @MarcGravell you have a point regarding concurrency - seems with a number of 5 parallel calls I get no more than 30-40% rebate when comparing to consecutive calls with this particular API. That said, this is still an improvement. Thanks again